# How to disable a notification channel on Android?

Tags: android, flutter

As a user, I can go to the phone settings -> myApp -> notifications -> channels and manually disable one notification channel, while still keeping other channels active and able to send notifications.

I tried to delete the channel but i get error:

```
PlatformException(error, Not allowed to delete channel my_foreground with a foreground service, null, java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to delete channel my_foreground with a foreground service
```

Is it possible to do a similar behaviour but programatically?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask